# JPQL (Hibernate implementation) select with join issues

Tags: java, hibernate, war, jpql

I'm having a bit of a rough time with JPQL (using Hibernate).

I have 2 Entities:

```
package org.oscarehr.common.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
@Table(name="spireAccessionNumberMap")
public class SpireAccessionNumberMap extends AbstractModel<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="uaccn")
    private Integer uaccn;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="uaccn_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<SpireCommonAccessionNumber> commonAccessionNumbers = new ArrayList<SpireCommonAccessionNumber>();

    public SpireAccessionNumberMap() {
    }

    public SpireAccessionNumberMap(Integer uniqueAccn) {
        this.uaccn = uniqueAccn;
    }


    //@Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    public Integer getUniqueAccessionNumber() {
        return uaccn;
    }

    public void setUniqueAccessionNumber(Integer uaccn) {
        this.uaccn = uaccn;
    }

    public List<SpireCommonAccessionNumber> getCommonAccessionNumbers() {
        return commonAccessionNumbers;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Iterator<SpireCommonAccessionNumber> i = this.commonAccessionNumbers.iterator();
        SpireCommonAccessionNumber commonAccessionNumber;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            commonAccessionNumber = i.next();
            commonAccessionNumber.setUniqueAccessionId(this.uaccn);         
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
package org.oscarehr.common.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
@Table(name="spireCommonAccessionNumber")
public class SpireCommonAccessionNumber extends AbstractModel<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="caccn")
    private String caccn;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uaccn_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Integer uaccn_id;




    //@Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    public String getCommonAccessionNumber() {
        return caccn;
    }

    public void setCommonAccessionNumber(String caccn) {
        this.caccn = caccn;
    }


    public Integer getUniqueAccessionId() {
        return uaccn_id;
    }

    public void setUniqueAccessionId(Integer uaccn_id) {
        this.uaccn_id = uaccn_id;
    }
}
```

Basically, I have the 'map' object, which has a unique number associated with it.  The map object has a 'link' to 1 or more 'commonNumber' objects, which store a 'common' number.

The idea is to be able to map lots of common numbers to a unique number using the JPQL and 'Dao's.

However, when I deploy my java WAR file, I get this error:

```
2013-01-04 13:42:12,344 INFO  [Version:14] Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
2013-01-04 13:42:12,347 INFO  [Version:16] Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
2013-01-04 13:42:17,753 ERROR [ContextLoader:215] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring_jpa.xml]: Invocati
on of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on org.oscarehr.common.model.SpireCommonAccessionNumber.uaccn_
id references an unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.oscarehr.common.web.OscarSpringContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(OscarSpringContextLoader.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on org.oscarehr.common.model.SpireCommonAccessionNumber.uaccn_id references an unknown entity: java.lang.Integer
        at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processEndOfQueue(AnnotationConfiguration.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(AnnotationConfiguration.java:438)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1226)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:131)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 28 more
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here...I've tried fiddling around with different ways to map the 'common' object to the 'map' object, but I keep getting errors.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping for the @ManyToOne seems like it should be.

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="uaccn_id")
private SpireAccessionNumberMap spireAccessionNumberMap;


public SpireAccessionNumberMap getSpireAccessionNumberMap() {
    return spireAccessionNumberMap;
}

public void setSpireAccessionNumberMap(
        SpireAccessionNumberMap spireAccessionNumberMap) {
    this.spireAccessionNumberMap = spireAccessionNumberMap;
}
```

The OneToMany side needs the following mapping.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="spireAccessionNumberMap")
private List<SpireCommonAccessionNumber> commonAccessionNumbers = new ArrayList<SpireCommonAccessionNumber>();
```

Comment: hmm...thanks @Manuel, it deploys now :)  But I'm getting an exception when I try to save: `SQLException: null,  message from server: "Column 'uaccn_id' cannot be null"`  I'm confused tho, since I thought that the jpql would 'handle' setting the uaccn_id for me...

Comment: Hmmm...I had a 'NOT NULL' condition on the mysql table, once I removed that I was ok...not sure why.  I may give your solution a shot, maybe it'll work with that "NOT NULL" condition.  Thanks @Manuel